# Como poner un fragment dentro de otro fragment? Con Chips no Pestañas!

Tags: java, android, scroll, fragment, menu

Problema al llamar al metodo (loadfragment) tengo un menú inferior que me lleva a diferentes fragment y tengo el siguiente problema en uno de estos fragment tengo puesto un chipgroup en la parte superior para navegar a diferentes especificaciones de la información relacionada a este fragment lo puedo hace con activitys pero se vería muy brusco el cambio y muy lento, sería ideal poner un nuevo grupo de fragmentos para cada una de estas especificaciones y mantener el menú inferior e ir cambiando de fragment cuando se cambie de opción en los chips también manteniendo estos últimos en la parte superior.

```js
package com.catalogo.yusliel;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import com.google.android.material.chip.Chip;

public class PeliFragment extends Fragment {

    View myFragment;
    Chip chaccion, chaventura, chcomando, chcomedia, chfantacia, chficcion, chromance, chsuspense, chaterror;
    Fragment fragmen;

    public PeliFragment(){

    }

    public static PeliFragment newInstance() {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        PeliFragment fragment = new PeliFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        myFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_peli, container, false);

        chaccion=myFragment.findViewById(R.id.chpaccion);
        chaventura=myFragment.findViewById(R.id.chpaventura);
        chcomando=myFragment.findViewById(R.id.chpcomando);
        chcomedia=myFragment.findViewById(R.id.chpcomedia);
        chfantacia=myFragment.findViewById(R.id.chpfantasia);
        chficcion=myFragment.findViewById(R.id.chpficcion);
        chromance=myFragment.findViewById(R.id.chpromance);
        chsuspense=myFragment.findViewById(R.id.chpsuspence);
        chaterror=myFragment.findViewById(R.id.chpterror);

        
        fragmen=null;
        chaccion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fragmen = new p_accion_Fragment();
            }
        });

        chaventura.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fragmen = new p_aventura_Fragment();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Aventuras", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        chcomando.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fragmen = new p_comando_Fragment();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Comando", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        chcomedia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fragmen = new p_comedia_Fragment();
            }
        });

        chcomedia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fragmen = new p_comedia_Fragment();
            }
        });

        chfantacia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fragmen = new p_fantacia_Fragment();
            }
        });

        chficcion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fragmen = new p_ficcion_Fragment();
            }
        });

        chromance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fragmen = new p_romance_Fragment();
            }
        });

        chsuspense.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fragmen = new p_suspence_Fragment();
            }
        });

        chaterror.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fragmen = new p_terror_Fragment();
            }
        });

        loadfragment(fragmen);

        return myFragment;

    }

    private void loadfragment(Fragment fragmen) {
       getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containergeneros,fragmen).commit();
    }


}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/pelicula_fragment"
    android:background="#0E0E0E"
    tools:context=".PeliFragment">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:id="@+id/chgrupo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:singleSelection="true">

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chpaccion"
                style="@style/CustomChipStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="@string/chpaccion"
                android:textAlignment="center"

                />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chpaventura"
                style="@style/CustomChipStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/chpaventura"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chpcomando"
                style="@style/CustomChipStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/chpcomando"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chpcomedia"
                style="@style/CustomChipStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/chpcomedia"
                android:textAlignment="center"

                />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chpfantasia"
                style="@style/CustomChipStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/chpfantacia"
                android:textAlignment="center"

                />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chpficcion"
                style="@style/CustomChipStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/chpficcion"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chpromance"
                style="@style/CustomChipStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/chpromance"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chpsuspence"
                style="@style/CustomChipStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/chpsuspence"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chpterror"
                style="@style/CustomChipStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/chpterror"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

        </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containergeneros"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Hola  yus , bienvenido, tu pregunta se parece a "tengo este ejercicio, háganlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, 
mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.